# how to empty a database in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

We have an old database in oracle 10g. we want to replace it with the new dmp file (that is what we have). Can I simply drop the old database, then run the impdp to create a new one? We are not worried about the data in the old database. Could you give me the steps to do that?

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the entire database or just one schema (=user)? The term "*database*" in Oracle refers to the whole installation including all schemas/users that you have created.

Comment: just one schema. I guess. Anyway, i was told if dmp file is used, it will recreate everything. Can I use impdp SYSTEM/password to do that?

Comment: Do a `drop user foobar cascade` beforehand. And yes impdp is the way to go (if the .dmp was created using expdp and not with exp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been stated in the comments, you can just drop the user with cascade, then import the user.

If you created an export with the older exp command, and it was an export of just one user/schema, then you will likely have to create the user/schema manually before running the imp. exp/imp were not as smart about that as expdp/impdp.